WooCommerce - Show Some Product Attributes on a Category page including the Attribute Label
There are many questions relating to this subject, however, none (that I can find) addressing this specific problem.
Using a variation of code I found on StackOverflow I am able to display the product attributes on a category page...
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_some_attributes', 5 );
function display_some_attributes() {

     global $product;

    $categories = array( '18' ); // Here your category terms ids, slugs or names

    if ( $product->is_type('simple') && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $attributes = array('Litres', 'Gallons', 'Diameter', 'Wall Height'); // here you defined attribute slugs
        $output     = array(); // Initializing

        // Loop through product attributes
        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
        $label_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
                $taxonomy = 'pa_' . $attribute;
                $values   = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);

            // If not empty add it to the array
            if ( ! empty($values) ) {
                $output[] = '<p class="attribute-" '.$attribute .' '. $taxonomy .' "><span id="att-label">' . $label_name . '</span> ' . $values . '</p>';
            }
        }
        // Convert array to a separated string by pipes
        echo implode('', $output);
    }
}

I am trying display the attribute "Label" as you can see from my attempt in the "$output" statement. I would have thought that ' . $label_name . ' would have worked but I guess not.
Does anyone have any insight with this.
I tried editing the $output section of the code with partial success (i get the taxonomy slug) but not the taxonomy label.

$values   = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy); will return only values. While using $product->get_attributes(); will return all data. You can try $label_name = wc_attribute_label($taxonomy); Also you define $taxonomy after $label_name you have to first get $taxonomy .
